# How to define `last` iterator without collecting/allocating?

Tags: interface, iterator, julia

Using the example from the [Julia Docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/), we can define an iterator like the following:

```
struct Squares
    count::Int
end

Base.iterate(S::Squares, state=1) = state > S.count ? nothing : (state*state, state+1)

Base.eltype(::Type{Squares}) = Int # Note that this is defined for the type
Base.length(S::Squares) = S.count
```

But even though there's a `length` defined, asking for `last(Squares(5))` results in an error:

```
julia> last(Squares(5))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching lastindex(::Squares)
```

Since `length` is defined, is there a way to iterate through and return the last value without doing an allocating `collect`? If so, would it be bad to extend the `Base.last` method for my type?

Comment: In any case allocation by `collect` shouldn't be used. `foldl((x,y)->y, Squares(5), init=nothing)` gets the last element with no allocations.

Comment: Thanks, I also found that `Itertools.nth` would efficiently index my iterator, and since I knew the length I could also define `Base.lastindex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in the docstring of `last`:

> Get the last element of an ordered collection, if it can be computed in O(1) time. This is accomplished by calling `lastindex` to get the last index.

The crucial part is O(1) computation time. In your example the cost of computing last element is O(`count`) (of course if we want to use the definition of the iterator as in general it would be possible compute it in O(1) time).

The idea is to avoid defining `last` for collections for which it is expensive to compute it. For this reason the default definition of last is:

```
last(a) = a[end]
```

which requires not only `lastindex` but also `getindex` defined for the passed value (as the assumption is that if someone defines `lastindex` and `getindex` for some type then these operations can be performed fast).

If you look at [Interfaces](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#Interfaces) section of the Julia manual you will notice that the iteration interface (something that your example implements) is less demanding than indexing interface (something that is defined for your example in the next section of the manual). Usually the distinction is made that indexing interface is only added for collections that can be indexed efficiently.

If you still want `last` to work on your type you can either:

- add a definition to `Base.last` specifically - there is nothing wrong with doing this;
- add a definition of `getindex`, `firstindex`, and `lastindex` to make the collection indexable (and then the default definition of `last` would work) - this is the approach presented in the Julia manual